# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hn4hol_z/spacy/

Tags: python, macos, installation, package, remote-server

I'm trying to install a Python package called "mudes" on another server using terminal. When I want to install it using

```
pip install mudes
```

or

```
pip3 install mudes
```

, I get the following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hn4hol_z/spacy/
```

I have also used

```
pip install --no-cache-dir mudes
```

, which resulted in the same error and

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools --user python
```

, which resulted in the following:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Collecting python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue trying to install pycaret. I'm no expert so I don't know why but this work for me

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

The setuptools might be outdated. Try running this command first and see if it helps.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: running this gives me the same original error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like spacy is not installed.

```
pip3 install spacy
```

It worked for me, check if it helps you.